# Fix first element, shuffle the rest of a list/array

Tags: python, shuffle

Is it possible to shuffle only a (continuous) part of a given list (or array in numpy)?

If this is not generally possible, how about the special case where the first element is fixed while the rest of the list/array need to be shuffled? For example, I have a list/array:

```
to_be_shuffled = [None, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', ...]
```

where the first element should always stay, while the rest are going to be shuffled repeatedly.

One possible way is to shuffle the whole list first, and then check the first element, if it is not the special fixed element (e.g. `None`), then swap its position with that of the special element (which would then require a lookup).

Is there any better way for doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

numpy arrays don't copy data on slicing:

```
numpy.random.shuffle(a[1:])
```

Comment: As I choose to implement using a numpy array, this is the best solution in my case. Other solutions are also very helpful and hope others find them suitable in their respective use cases.

Answer (score 10):

Why not just

```
import random
rest = to_be_shuffled[1:]
random.shuffle(rest)
shuffled_lst = [to_be_shuffled[0]] + rest
```

Comment: @DavidRobinson, thanks. Is the above in-place, meaning there is no new copy of part of the list/array created?

Comment: @kojiro `shuffled_lst` doesn't exist before that. You probably mean: `to_be_shuffled[1:] = rest`

Comment: @skyork no, both `shuffled_lst` and `rest` are copies (partial and complete) of the data in `to_be_shuffled`.

Comment: skyork: No, the code isn't in place; the order of `to_be_shuffled` isn't changed. `to_be_shuffled[1:]` makes a copy.

Comment: @DavidRobinson, i see. i guess for in-place solution, my suggestion above would do the job albeit not very efficiently? Is there any other better in-place solution out there?

Comment: @JFSebastian's answer notes that you can do a numpy array in place this way. However, why does it have to be in place? However large your list is, the bottleneck will almost certainly be in shuffling it rather than copying it.

Comment: @skyork: [Joel Cornett's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11706463/4279) that mimics stdlib implementation should work

Answer (score 4):

I thought it would be interesting and educational to try to implement a slightly more general approach than what you're asking for. Here I shuffle the *indices* to the original list (rather than the list itself), excluding the locked indices, and use that index-list to cherry pick elements from the original list. This is not an in-place solution, but implemented as a generator so you can lazily pick elements.

Feel free to edit if you can improve it.

```
import random

def partial_shuf(input_list, fixed_indices):
    """Given an input_list, yield elements from that list in random order
    except where elements indices are in fixed_indices."""
    fixed_indices = sorted(set(i for i in fixed_indices if i < len(input_list)))
    i = 0
    for fixed in fixed_indices:
        aslice = range(i, fixed)
        i = 1 + fixed
        random.shuffle(aslice)
        for j in aslice:
            yield input_list[j]
        yield input_list[fixed]
    aslice = range(i, len(input_list))
    random.shuffle(aslice)
    for j in aslice:
        yield input_list[j]

print '\n'.join(' '.join((str(i), str(n))) for i, n in enumerate(partial_shuf(range(4, 36), [0, 4, 9, 17, 25, 40])))

assert sorted(partial_shuf(range(4, 36), [0, 4, 9, 17, 25, 40])) == range(4, 36)
```

Answer (score 3):

I took the shuffle function from the standard library `random` module (found in `Lib\random.py`) and modified it slightly so that it shuffles only a portion of the list specified by `start` and `stop`. It does this in place. Enjoy!

```
from random import randint

def shuffle(x, start=0, stop=None):
    if stop is None:
        stop = len(x)

    for i in reversed(range(start + 1, stop)):
        # pick an element in x[start: i+1] with which to exchange x[i]
        j = randint(start, i)
        x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i]
```

For your purposes, calling this function with `1` as the `start` parameter should do the trick.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: That I did sir. Thanks!

Comment: Use xrange instead of range on Python 2.x